# Laravel - constrain on eager loaded belongsTo relationship

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My model `Book`

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Author');
}
```

I want to get all books which have authors that have column is_published == 1.

So I have tried this:

```
Book::with(['author' => function($query){

   $query->where('is_published', '=', '1');  

}]);
```

This works but really only gets me Books where SOME books have author model attached and some don't!

So, I tried this:

```
Book::with(['author' => function($query){

   $query->where('is_published', '=', '1');  

}])->has('author');
```

But I get this error:

`Has method invalid on "belongsTo" relations`

How can I be sure that my constraint on the foreign table reduces my final data set without having to loop through my data and check for the existence of the author? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that eager loading does not utilise the SQL `JOIN` (that I know of) if you head over to http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading you will see the example:

```
select * from books

select * from authors where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)
```

This does not allow the constraint of the author existing.

To do this it requires a `JOIN` if you want to do it efficiently (I assume so hence the eager loading).

Relevant Laravel Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins

Answer (score 1):

```
Book::whereHas('author' , function($query){
   $query->where('is_published', '=', '1');  
})->get();
```

Use this it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `has('author')` with `whereNotNull('author_id')`.

Comment: this doesn't work because author_id is never null. We always have an author_id.